# How would I combine these 2 similar functions?

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

I have created two functions that run a similar set of IF statements, one shows the cost of a game, the other its name. I have used "onclick" to display both values in my form. It all works but suffers from bloat. Is there a way to combine both functions to shorten the script?

```
        function GameTitle() {
var textboxValue = document.getElementById("game_id").value;
    var message;
    if (textboxValue == 1) {
        message = "Fantasy World";
    } else if (textboxValue == 2) {
        message = "Sir Wags A Lot";
    } else if (textboxValue == 3) {
        message = "Take a Path";
    } else if (textboxValue == 4) {
        message = "River Clean Up";
    } else if (textboxValue == 5) {
        message = "PinBall";
    } else if (textboxValue == 6) {
        message = "Ghost girl";
    } else if (textboxValue == 7) {
        message = "Dress Up";
    } else if (textboxValue == 8) {
        message = "Where is my hat?";
    } else {
        message = "Invalid ID";
    }
document.getElementById("game_title").value = message;
}

//Display price of Game
    function Cost() {
var textboxValue = document.getElementById("game_id").value;
    var cost;
    if (textboxValue == 1) {
        cost = "0.99";
    } else if (textboxValue == 2) {
        cost = "0.99";
    } else if (textboxValue == 3) {
        cost = "1.99";
    } else if (textboxValue == 4) {
        cost = "1.99";
    } else if (textboxValue == 5) {
        cost = "3.99";
    } else if (textboxValue == 6) {
        cost = "3.99";
    } else if (textboxValue == 7) {
        cost = "1.99";
    } else if (textboxValue == 8) {
        cost = "1.99";
    } else {
        cost = "Invalid ID";
    }
document.getElementById("cost").value = cost;
}
```

Comment: Within the same function assign the value of message and cost why are you calling two function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to make the update to both fields at once.  Since your driving variable is one (`game_id`) for both factors (title and cost), then you should make the update to those two fields at once.  So, something like the following would do:

```js
 function updateGameTitleAndCost() {
   var textboxValue = document.getElementById("game_id").value;
   var message, cost;
   if (textboxValue == 1) {
     message = "Fantasy World";
     cost = "0.99";
   } else if (textboxValue == 2) {
     message = "Sir Wags A Lot";
     cost = "0.99";
   } else if (textboxValue == 3) {
     message = "Take a Path";
     cost = "1.99";
   } else if (textboxValue == 4) {
     message = "River Clean Up";
     cost = "1.99";
   } else if (textboxValue == 5) {
     message = "PinBall";
     cost = "3.99";
   } else if (textboxValue == 6) {
     message = "Ghost girl";
     cost = "3.99";
   } else if (textboxValue == 7) {
     message = "Dress Up";
     cost = "1.99";
   } else if (textboxValue == 8) {
     message = "Where is my hat?";
     cost = "1.99";
   } else {
     message = "Invalid ID";
     cost = "Invalid ID";
   }

   document.getElementById("game_title").value = message;
   document.getElementById("cost").value = cost;
 }
```

Comment: @ bigT  I wonder, would it be possible to calculate the price for the loan of a game by adding a few lines of code...I made a few changes to reflect this - though my initial test show there is a problem.

Comment: @RickTicky - Yes, I don't see why not.. If you will be doing any calculations that involve the cost you got from the `if` statement, you first need to make sure it is !== "Invalid ID", and then [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) it to get it's actual value in digits and not as a string.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an array of objects for this

```
var games = [
 {
  message : "Fantasy World",
  cost : 0.99
 },
 {
  message : "Sir Wags A Lot",
  cost : 0.99
 },
 {
  message : "Take a Path",
  cost : 1.99
 },
 {
  message : "River Clean Up",
  cost : 1.99
 },
 {
  message : "PinBall",
  cost : 3.99
 },
 {
  message : "Ghost girl",
  cost : 3.99
 },
 {
  message : "Dress Up",
  cost : 1.99
 },
 {
  message : "Where is my hat?",
  cost : 1.99
 }
];
```

And then in your function you can accept and id, reference its index in the array (offset by 1 for 0 based) and use that object.

```
function Display(){
 var textboxValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("game_id").value,10);
 document.getElementById("game_title").value = 
  textboxValue-1 < games.length ? games[textboxValue-1].message : "Invalid ID";
 document.getElementById("cost").value = 
  textboxValue-1 < games.length ? games[textboxValue-1].cost : "Invalid ID";
}
```

Comment: @spike - Good idea :) It is really the best way to handle something like this.

Comment: Did you mean to use `textboxValue - 1`?

Comment: Great suggestion for a new programmer!

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Your sarcasm is not constructive. Keep in mind, answers here are not just for the OP, but for the general group of people who will also find this answer in the future.

Comment: @TravisJ that wasn't sarcasm. I was genuinely saying that this is a good idea. If you're gonna be writing `if (x == 1) {...} else if (x == 2) {...} ...`, you really should switch to a hashmap or array.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Oh, my apologies! :( Sometimes tone is so hard to decipher online.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace IFs with simple map:

```
values = {
  "1": "0.99",
  "2": "0.99",
  ...
}
```

Then call it with:

```
cost = values[textboxValues]
```

So you just need 2 maps for you example. If the cost is not found with the line above, it means it should be "Invalid ID" value.

Update:

```
values = {
  "1": {
    cost: "0.99",
    name: "Sir Bunny Hopings"
  },
  "2": {..},
  ...
  }

Game = function() {
  var i = document.getElementById("game_id").value,
      game;

  game = values[id] || {cost: "Invalid ID", name: "Invalid iD"};

  document.getElementById("cost").value = game.cost;
  document.getElementById("game_title").value = game.name;
}
```

Comment: this seems promising - can it be used to update both fields at the same time?

Comment: @RickTicky this already does update both fields at the same time. No "if" statements are required. All you need to do is edit the `values` "array" (hashmap) to your values.